# What will the Binary Search Tree from this code look like?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I just want to visualise what this BST will look like after the code has been run! There is Tree1 and Tree2.

```
 public static void initialise_tree(myBinarySearchTree<Integer, String> t, boolean mode){
     t.my_insert(8, "A");

     t.my_insert(5, "B");

     t.my_insert(2, "C");

     t.my_insert(1, "D");

     t.my_insert(3, "E");

     t.my_insert(7, "G");

     t.my_insert(6, "H");

     t.my_insert(11, "I");

     t.my_insert(10, "J");

     if (mode == false)
    t.my_insert(9, "K");
   }
```

Tree1 has mode set to false, while Tree2 has mode set to true

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how the tree will look like or how to display visualisation of the tree using java?

Comment: Just what it will look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mode` set to `true`, it will look the following:

```
         (8, "A")
         /       \
    (5, "B")     (11, "I")
     /       \          /    
(2, "C")     (7, "G")  (10, "J")
   |    \         /           /
(1, "D")(3, "E") (6, "H")    (9, "K")
```

where `/` represents child on the left (with smaller value than its parent) and `\` represents child on the right (with bigger value than its parent).

With `mode` set to `true`, there will simply be no `(9, "K")` node.

Comment: Thanks! And is the 'mode == false' (with the 9) tree an unbalanced tree? And when the 9 is not there, it is a balanced tree?

Comment: That's correct. Do you know why will this tree be unbalanced with `9` added?

Comment: You should create a new question instead of "extending" your original question in a way that only comments can answer it.